# SQL sum rows by different date ranges

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum, date-range

I have a google bigquery table that captures daily usage data for all users, and each user has its own `Anchor_date` (when this user first started). `Usage` is recorded for each `User` on each `Date`.

In order to track usage **per subscription period**, I want to sum up all the usage between anchor dates (so if the anchor date was initially on `2014-01-23` for John, then its most recent (current month being 2021-05) subscription period should be `2021-04-23` up to `2021-05-22`, with usage being  `32 + ....+  24`. Then next cycle would be `2021-05-23` up to `2021-06-22` and so on.

```
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| date       |   User      | Usage      | Anchor_date         |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-04-01 |    John     | 10.00      | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-04-02 |    John     | 15.00      | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ...        |    ...      | ...        | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-04-23 |    John     | 32.00      | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ...        |    ...      | ...        | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-05-22 |    John     | 24.00      | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ...        |    ...      | ...        | 2014-01-23          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-04-02 |    Kevin    | 28.00      | 2015-04-02          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ...        |    ...      | ...        | 2015-04-02          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 2021-05-01 |    Kevin    | 32.00      | 2015-04-02          |
+------------+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

My goal is to get the total usage occurred within the most recent subscription period for each user. So final table should look something like this.

```
+-------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|   User      | Aggregated_usage | Start_date  | End_date  |
+-------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|    John     | 32 + ... + 24    | 2021-04-23  | 2021-05-22|
+-------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+ 
|    Kevin    | 28 + ... + 32    | 2021-04-02  | 2021-05-01|
+-------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
| ...         |    ...           | ...         | ...       |
+-------------+------------------+-- ----------+-----------+
```

So far I only kinda know how to get the start date and the end date of the most recent subscription period. This is throwing error for invalid date such as '2021-04-31' though.

```
date(extract(year from current_date()), extract(month from date_sub(current_date(), interval 30 day)), extract(day from anchor_date)) as start_date, 
date(extract(year from current_date()), extract(month from current_date()), extract(day from date_sub(anchor_date, interval 1 day))) as end_date
```

And doing a sum by these different date ranges seems pretty complex so I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Appreciate all the help!! Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and show sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what the image you have in the question is. Note that text tables are much preferred to images.

Comment: The description of the SQL tag explains that you should also include a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. Please [edit] your post to add that tag, along with sample data (as text, not an image) and the desired output you want from that data. (Images can't be copied and pasted to create test data to use to help write an answer - they should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem, which is not the case here.)

Comment: Hi there! I've added some additional comments. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH anchorAndEndDate AS (
SELECT user
   ,SUM(Usage) AS aggregated_usage
   ,MIN(Anchor_date) as anchor_date
   ,MAX(Date) as end_date
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 1)
SELECT
   user
   ,aggregated_usage
   ,DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(end_date, MONTH), INTERVAL -1 MONTH), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAY FROM anchor_date)-1 DAY) AS start_date 
   ,end_date
FROM anchorAndEndDate
```

Note it's best practice when writing SQL to name your columns in snake_case or camelCase.